# In SSMS how can I use the DATEADD function to grab all values between '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-09-01 023:59:00.000'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and trying to write a query to grab all values that have the next days date for orders I do not want to hard code the between clause for the date and want to use DateAdd or a similar function so it works consistently without changing the syntax.  Example of hard coded query is below.

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[INBOUNDORDHEADER]
between '2018-09-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-09-01 023:59:00.000'
```

What is the best way to write the syntax for this utilizing the DATEADD or similar function?

Is there a way I can not discriminate against the time of the values retrieved? For example just pull everything with 2018-09-01 and not exclude records based on their time format

Can I use AddDate with between to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not super elegant, but you can use a cast to DATE to strip the time:

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[INBOUNDORDHEADER]
BETWEEN DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(GETDATE() As DATE)) AND DATEADD(day, 2, CAST(GETDATE() As DATE))
```

This will give you the date range between midnight tomorrow and midnight the day after.  Using your example and today's date, it'll be BETWEEN '2018-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-09-02 00:00:00'

Comment: This is a viable solution, thank you for your input Evan.  I hope you have a great weekend.

Comment: If you're computing the two midnights, it's usual to convert from using `between` to using `>=` and `<`, so that anything that happens at precisely midnight isn't included in multiple ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Making the `WHERE` clause [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that it can benefit from indexes can greatly improve performance. It is best not to fiddle about with trying to get the "last" time in a day, just use a [half-open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology):

```
declare @Today as DateTime = Cast( GetDate() ); -- Strip the time-of-day.

select OrderId
  from [XXXX].[dbo].[INBOUNDORDHEADER]
  where DateAdd( day, 1, @Today ) <= OrderDate and OrderDate < DateAdd( day, 2, @Today );
```

Comment: Thank you @Habo I appreciate you providing a solution that is optimal, and providing me with a reference to consider sargability in the future.  I am currently still developing my skills and appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'cleanest' way is to use DATEFROMPARTS and DATEPART methods:

```
SELECT OrderId
FROM [XXXX].[dbo].[INBOUNDORDHEADER]
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate),
    DATEPART(MONTH, OrderDate),
    DATEPART(DAY, OrderDate)) = '2018-09-01'
```

Edit: This is not good for performance. See HABO's answer for the optimal way to do this.

Comment: Very interesting, I will try this and well and see which one the execution plan likes better.  I appreciate your input Dan, have a great weekend.

Comment: In general, applying functions to columns results in a `where` clause results in a query that is not [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), i.e. it can't benefit from index lookups.

Comment: @HABO is correct - this query will always perform worse than the one in HABO's answer.

Comment: Thank you both very much, this will help me in my educational process.  I appreciate both of your contributions.